# Inno Setup Simple progress page for Run section

Tags: progress-bar, inno-setup, pascalscript

My installer is very simple, it basically is:

1. Welcome Page
2. Progress Page
3. Final Page

The Welcome and Final pages are standard (just one button).
At the Progress page I'm installing a bunch of other programs silently.

The actual script is installing each program inside the `[Run] section.
The problem is that the bar reaches 100% and then stays there.
I'm only able to change the message text.

What I would like to achieve is to show the progress using Pascal Script (as it may allow me to have more flexibility), something like:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  ProgressPage.SetProgress(1, 100);
  exec(.......)
  ProgressPage.SetProgress(15, 100);
  exec(.......)
  ProgressPage.SetProgress(40, 100);
  ...
  ...
end;
```

That way I can show a more accurate progress bar. This is what I have (simulating installation. Taken from an example):

```pascal
[Code]

var
  ProgressPage: TOutputProgressWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  ProgressPage := CreateOutputProgressPage('My App','');
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpWelcome then begin
    ProgressPage.SetText('Starting installation...', '');
    ProgressPage.SetProgress(0, 0);
    ProgressPage.Show;
    try
      for I := 0 to 10 do begin
        ProgressPage.SetProgress(I, 10);
        Sleep(100);
      end;
    finally
      ProgressPage.Hide;
    end;
  end else
    Result := True;
end;
```

The problem is that when I build the installer it doesn't show the Welcome page (the installer is running, but nothing is shown).

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ergh, don't do it inside NextButtonClick. CurStepChanged(ssInstall) at the earliest.

Comment: Why not inside NextButtonClick? Its the first time I use PascalScripting in Inno Setup so I may not understand how it should be.

Comment: Because it can be called 1 or more time, it's also, on most installs, before the point the user has confirmed "yes, install this".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it!

I was missing :

- `Result := True;` after `ProgressPage.Hide;`
- `if CurPageID = wpReady` (Instead of `wpWelcome`)

That solved the problem!

Answer (score 5):

You can control the real progress bar position in code using `WizardForm.ProgressGauge`.

Comment: Can you point me to some example please? I can't find how it is used (only the documentation).

Comment: No example, but the Object reference int he help shows the properties you need to access. They can be called from the Before/AfterInstall entries of the [Run] entries.

Comment: I guess using WizardForm.ProgressGauge would be more simple and elegant. However, as I have no examples and my installer is working just fine (as it is) I can just up-vote your suggestion. I can't set it as correct answer as I can not test it. I hope you understand.

Comment: @lepe The example code is in my answer to [How to set the progress bar value in the \[Run\] section of the Inno Setup install script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34336466/850848)