# How to manipulate progress bar on Inno Setup Run section?

Tags: installation, progress-bar, inno-setup, pascalscript

Similar to this question:
[How to set the progress bar value in the [Run] section of the Inno Setup install script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8502049/850848)

When the Inno Setup gets to the `[Run]` section, the progress bar shows at 100% and stops in this position.

I have many files that I install in this `Run` section, which I wish to restart the progress bar and control it, as it goes installing each program.

The status message is easy to change (`StatusMsg`), but the progress I'm missing something. Could you guys help me out, please?

Example:

```
[Run]
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""msxml.msi"" /quiet"; \
    StatusMsg: "MSXML..."; Flags: runascurrentuser
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""capicom_dc_sdk.msi"" /quiet"; \
    StatusMsg: "CAPICOM..."; Flags: runascurrentuser
```

Since I want to control the progress bar during it's installation, I don't know what to do. I thought in maybe using `BeforeInstall` parameter, creating a code to set the progress bar to 0 by doing something like `WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Position = 0;` and in the `AfterInstall` parameter, the opposite, `WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Position = 100;`, but how to change during the installation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It would be rather difficult to update the progress bar, while another process is running.

I do not see a point of endeavoring it, as you are unlikely able to tell the progress of the sub-installer, so you won't know what to update the progress bar to.

Except for special cases, when the sub-installer provides an API to report its progress.
For an example, see:

- [Inno Setup Get progress from .NET Framework 4.5 (or higher) installer to update progress bar position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39247947/850848) or
- [Make Inno Setup Installer report its installation progress status to master installer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40947436/850848).

---

To update the progress bar according to number of sub-installers finished, you can do:

```pascal
[Run]
FileName: "process1"; BeforeInstall: SetProgress(0); AfterInstall: SetProgress(33)
FileName: "process2"; AfterInstall: SetProgress(66)
FileName: "process3"; AfterInstall: SetProgress(100)

[Code]

procedure SetProgress(Position: Integer);
begin
  WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Position :=
    Position * WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Max div 100;
end;
```

To divide part of the progress range for installing files and the rest to running the sub-installers, see
[Inno Setup - Prevent extraction of files from setting progress bar to 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36314079/850848)

---

Another option is to use a "marquee" (= infinite) progress bar style.

See [Progress bar control styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/progress-bar-control-styles).

```pascal
[Run]
FileName: "process1"; BeforeInstall: SetMarqueeProgress(True)
FileName: "process2"
FileName: "process3"; AfterInstall: SetMarqueeProgress(False)

[Code]

procedure SetMarqueeProgress(Marquee: Boolean);
begin
  if Marquee then
  begin
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstMarquee;
  end
    else
  begin
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstNormal;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

Works even on Windows XP, despite not being listed in the official Microsoft documentation anymore. Tested on Windows XP SP3.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to Martin Prikryl answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34349900):

When this style should be set on the uninstall form, the call looks slightly different:

```
procedure SetMarqueeProgressUninstall(Marquee: Boolean);
begin
  if Marquee then
  begin
    UninstallProgressForm.ProgressBar.Style := npbstMarquee;
  end
    else
  begin
    UninstallProgressForm.ProgressBar.Style := npbstNormal;
  end;
end;
```

This can be easily called from the `InitializeUninstallProgressForm` event and the original one from `InitializeWizard` if there are no files to be installed at all.