# Inno Setup: How to manipulate progress bar on Registering section?

Tags: installation, progress-bar, inno-setup, pascalscript

Just like my question in [Inno Setup: How to manipulate progress bar on Run section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34336466/inno-setup-how-to-manipulate-progress-bar-on-run-section), which Martin Prikryl gave me an excellent suggestion, I want to do the same (change the style of the progress gauge) in the registering section, I mean, just before the `Run` section, when Inno Setup registers the DLLs / OCXs (`regserver` flag in `[Files]`).

I tried using some of the `PageID` to make it work, which I think is the `wpInstalling` one, comparing it to when it values goes to 100, it changes to Marquee style, but I didn't make it work.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no event that is triggered before the registration.

---

The closest you can get is using [`AfterInstall` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptinstall) of *the last installed file* (not the .dll):

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "mydll.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: regserver
Source: "myfile1"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "myfile2"; DestDir: "{app}"
...
Source: "myfileN"; DestDir: "{app}"; AfterInstall: AfterLastFileInstall

[Code]

procedure AfterLastFileInstall;
begin
  Log('Last file installed, file registration is starting');
  WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstMarquee;
end;
```

---

Another option is to handle [`CurInstallProgressChanged` event](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurInstallProgressChanged) and wait for `CurProgress` = `MaxProgress`:

```pascal
[Code] 

procedure CurInstallProgressChanged(CurProgress, MaxProgress: Integer);
begin
  if CurProgress >= MaxProgress then
  begin
    Log('Everything is installed, file registration is starting');
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstMarquee;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Martin, once again, thanks. I used the procedure CurInstallProgressChanged.