# Inno Setup - Prevent extraction of files from setting progress bar to 100%

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

In the Inno Setup `wpInstalling` page how can I prevent the initial extraction of the files as defined in the `[Files]` section from setting the progress bar to (almost) 100%?

[image]

My installation script mainly consists of installing a number of third party installation files from the '[Run]' section. Example below:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\vcredist_x86-2010-sp1.exe"; Parameters: "/q /norestart"; \
  Check: InstallVCRedist;  \
  BeforeInstall: UpdateProgress(10, 'Installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable - 10.0.40219...');
Filename: "{tmp}\openfire_3_8_1.exe"; Check: InstallOpenFire; \
  BeforeInstall: UpdateProgress(25, 'Installing OpenFire 3.8.1...');
Filename: "{tmp}\postgresql-8.4.16-2-windows.exe"; \
  Parameters: "--mode unattended --unattendedmodeui none --datadir ""{commonappdata}\PostgreSQL\8.4\data"" --install_runtimes 0"; \
  Check: InstallPostgreSQL; \
  BeforeInstall: UpdateProgress(35, 'Installing PostgreSQL 8.4...'); \
  AfterInstall: UpdateProgress(50, 'Setting up database...');
```

The installation of these third party components takes longer than any other part of the install (by far) but unfortunately the progress bar goes from 0% to close to 100% during the initial extraction of these files. I then can reset the progress bar to an amount of my choosing by using the following procedure:

```pascal
procedure UpdateProgress(Position: Integer; StatusMsg: String);
begin
  WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := StatusMsg;
  WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Position := 
    Position * WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Max div 100;
end;
```

Ideally however I'd prefer the initial extraction to instead go from 0–10% (approx.) as that would more closely represent what is actually happening.

Is there any event to capture the progression of the extraction of the files or alternatively a way to prevent or block the extraction of the files from updating the progress bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to increase the `WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Max`.

But unfortunately there's no event that happens after the Inno Setup sets its initial maximum.

You can abuse the [`BeforeInstall` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptinstall) of the first installed file though.

And then in the `[Run]` section, use the `AfterInstall` to progress the bar.

This expands on my answer to [Inno Setup: How to manipulate progress bar on Run section?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34336466/850848)

```
[Files]
Source: "vcredist_x86-2010-sp1.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; \
    BeforeInstall: SetProgressMax(10)
Source: "openfire_3_8_1.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"

[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\vcredist_x86-2010-sp1.exe"; AfterInstall: UpdateProgress(55);
Filename: "{tmp}\openfire_3_8_1.exe"; AfterInstall: UpdateProgress(100);
```

```pascal
[Code]

procedure SetProgressMax(Ratio: Integer);
begin
  WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Max := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Max * Ratio;
end;

procedure UpdateProgress(Position: Integer);
begin
  WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Position :=
    Position * WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Max div 100;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. That worked like a charm. You're a saint and a scholar sir. I've always liked the Czech people - now even more so. Have a markup.