# Show progress details (like speed) when installing files with Inno Setup

Tags: progress-bar, inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm trying to add a dynamic progress bar in my installer. I want to install some programs with my installer. The progress bar literally should show, which program files are currently install right now. It should look like this example:

[image]

I do try something like this : [Inno Setup: How to manipulate progress bar on Run section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34336466/inno-setup-how-to-manipulate-progress-bar-on-run-section)

```pascal
[Code]

procedure UpdateProgress(Position: Integer);
begin
  WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Position := Position * WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Max div 100;
end;
```

But I also want to see the the actual speed, status, elapsed time, etc.
Is there an opportunity to realize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inno Setup API does not give you the information you would need to implement this (state of an installation of a specific file).

So it's not possible (unless you add the functionality to Inno Setup).