# inno setup % percentage progress bar

Tags: inno-setup

Anyone know how to put a percentage% of the progress bar down the bar

ex: edited image in photoshop inno setup 5.5.1-unicode+Script ISDone 0.6 thanks

[image]

Comment: And why would we help you pirate stuff exactly?

Comment: Maybe it was just an example from an existing installer?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put the percentage label on the *Installing* [wizard page](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=wizardpages), then I think it is not possible. But you could use the [CreateOutputProgressPage](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_createoutputprogresspage.htm) which let you control the progressbar and you can add a percentage label via Pascal Script.

```
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  Page: TOutputProgressWizardPage;
  PercentLabel: TLabel;
begin
  Page := CreateOutputProgressPage('Caption', 'Description');
  Page.ProgressBar.Show;
  PercentLabel := TLabel.Create(Page);
  PercentLabel.Top := Page.ProgressBar.Top + 20;
  PercentLabel.Caption := '0%';
  ...
end;
```

Also read this question: [Inno Setup Simple progress page for Run section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6921254/256544). It demonstrates how to control the progress.

Comment: Thank splash but did not modify the place I got down but the size of the numbers but not

Left: = ISDoneProgressBar1.Width ScaleX + (-150);
Top: = ScaleY ISDoneProgressBar1.Top + (100);

Comment: From now on you can use the new [`CurInstallProgressChanged event`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/issues/51) to calculate the percentage.

Comment: @TLama: Thanks for the notification and your work on this!