# Installer doesn't accept mouse input while processing Run entry

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to execute several installers using **[Run]**.
My problem is, since each entry might take up to 1-2 minute(s), my installer window becomes frozen. I can't Cancel, I can't Re-size, and most disturbingly, I can't Move the window.

Here's the method I use:

```
[Run]    
Filename: "{tmp}\DesktopLinkSetup.exe";
StatusMsg: "Installing Desktop Link. Please wait, this can take up to 1 min";
Flags: runhidden;
Parameters: "/VERYSILENT";

Filename: "{tmp}\NotificationLinkSetup.exe";
StatusMsg: "Installing Notification Link. Please wait, this can take up to 2 min";
Flags: runhidden;
Parameters: "/VERYSILENT";
```

I know [Run] might have blocked my UI thread, but is there any way to make window react to user mouse control? like Move Window?

thanks

Comment: Nope, as long as you'd run those applications from a worker thread.

Comment: Then that requires writing DLL right?

Comment: Cannot say requires (as I don't know if the required WinAPI functions could be translated into the pure Inno Setup Pascal Script), but a lot easier is to wrap it into a DLL (just do not think about C# ;-)

Comment: I don't have my environment with me, but I guess if I use nowait as its Flag, it won't block UI anymore. But then it will cause another problem. My wizard might finish before all run entry finish.

Comment: But there's no way out of this. Even if you'd make a function that would be [`waiting for the application to finish`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10910780/960757) in a loop, you won't pump up the main thread message loop (Delphi has `Application.ProcessMessages` method for that, but it's not published by Inno Setup), which is necessary to keep the UI *alive*.

Comment: I've seen someone [simulating progress bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921254/innosetup-simple-progress-wizard)  by setting each Run entry to noWait, and using "for loop" with progress update code and Sleep() inside it in [Code] section to simulate progress bar update. I've tried this method and this provides the best user experience. But I really think this is a dirty solution. Is this method typically used? or is the method I proposed above used more often?